# How to sort the layer list in Multiple selection window?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, qgis-2

Multiple selection window pops up when you want to select input layer(s) within Processing Tools.

The order of layers in `Multiple selection` window seems not corresponding to Layer Panel.

How to sort out the layer list in QGIS `Multiple selection` window?

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in QGIS 3.0 - I don't believe there's plans to change the 2.x releases correspondingly

Comment: Thanks. That's great news! So I will try some dev nightly while waiting the release date next two week.